# How to Refresh Main Activity in Kotlin without closing the App

Tags: android, kotlin

How to refresh kotlin ActivityMain page every 5 minutes once without closing the app. Refreshing the Activity without user notice

Comment: Please elaborate by "refreshing activity".  Much better if you can post a sample snippet of your project.

Answer (score 1):

There is an activity function called `recreate()` which redraws the activity. If you want to loop that every 5min it would look something like this:

```
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        try {
            recreate()
        } catch (e: Exception) {}
        handler.postDelayed(this, 300000)
    }
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 300000)
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue. Can I execute this one at particular time like 9PM in the night.

Comment: This answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856960/set-timer-for-specific-time-not-interval

Comment: Its not working. val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")            val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())   System.out.println(" C DATE is  "+currentDate) 
        val currentDate2 = "04:15"  val handler = Handler()  val runnable = object : Runnable {      override fun run() {
                try {


                    if(currentDate==currentDate2)
                    {
                        recreate()
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {}
                handler.postDelayed(this, 60000)
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000)

Comment: Okay, then try evernote's android job library: https://github.com/evernote/android-job/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-run-a-job-at-a-specific-time-once-a-day